boost cobalt+asio not throwing exceptions correctly?
I have a simple piece of boost cobalt+asio code here to resolve a URL to an endpoint.

It works fine when the URL is a valid host.
It should throw when the URL does not specify a valid host, but does not.  Instead it prints an error message to stderr and SIGABRTs.

#include <boost/cobalt.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace net               = boost::asio;
namespace cobalt            = boost::cobalt;
using executor_type         = cobalt::executor;

cobalt::task<std::vector<net::ip::tcp::endpoint>> resolve(
    executor_type executor,
    std::string const& hostname,
    std::string const& service
)
{
    auto endpoints = std::vector<net::ip::tcp::endpoint>{};
    auto resolver = net::ip::tcp::resolver{executor};
    try
    {
        auto results = co_await resolver.async_resolve(
            hostname,
            service,
            cobalt::use_op);

        for (const auto& result : results)
            endpoints.push_back(result.endpoint());

        co_return endpoints;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Resolve exception\n";
        throw;
    }
}

cobalt::task<void> main2()
{
    auto executor = co_await cobalt::this_coro::executor;

    auto endpoints = co_await resolve(executor, "www.googleqqq.com", "https"); // Intentionally wrong; use www.google.com to make it work

    // Print the resolved endpoints
    for (const auto& endpoint : endpoints)
        std::cerr << endpoint << std::endl;

    co_return;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        net::io_context ctx;
        cobalt::spawn(ctx, main2(), net::detached);
        ctx.run();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Uncaught exception\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

And the CMakeLists.txt:

NOTE: I did not want to force people to install boost on their system, hence the FetchContent. THIS WILL TAKE A FEW MINUTES TO BUILD.
NOTE: It expects that OpenSSL is installed though.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.30)
project(async_resolve_exception_issue)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(FetchContent)

# OpenSSL
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)

# Boost
FetchContent_Declare(
    boost
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git
    GIT_TAG boost-1.85.0
    GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
    GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
    OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(boost)
find_package(Boost 1.85 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${PROJECT_NAME}.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        Boost::beast
        Boost::cobalt
        OpenSSL::SSL
        OpenSSL::Crypto
)

I invoke with:
build/async_resolve_exception_issue 

And the error message is:
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type boost::detail::with_throw_location<boost::system::system_error>: Host not found (authoritative) [asio.netdb:1]

I am using MacOS Sonoma (14.6) + cmake 3.30.2 + clang 18.1.8

The answer is the same as the answer to this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78860001/boost-asio-with-coroutines-not-throwing-exceptions-correctly
