boost asio (with coroutines) not throwing exceptions correctly?
This is intentionally a near-duplicate of:
boost cobalt+asio not throwing exceptions correctly?
The difference is that the other ticket uses boost cobalt (a library that sits on top of asio that adds a more "co-routiney" interface).
This ticket applies to only asio, without cobalt, and the code has been modified accordingly.  You can use the same CMakeLists.txt as the cobalt ticket.
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace net = boost::asio;
using executor_type =  net::any_io_executor;

net::awaitable<std::vector<net::ip::tcp::endpoint>> resolve(
    executor_type executor,
    std::string const& hostname,
    std::string const& service
)
{
    auto endpoints = std::vector<net::ip::tcp::endpoint>{};
    auto resolver = net::ip::tcp::resolver{executor};
    try
    {
        auto results = co_await resolver.async_resolve(hostname, service, net::use_awaitable);

        for (const auto& result : results)
            endpoints.push_back(result.endpoint());

        co_return endpoints;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Resolve exception\n";
        throw;
    }
}

net::awaitable<void> main2()
{
    auto executor = co_await net::this_coro::executor;

    auto endpoints = co_await resolve(executor, "www.googleqqq.com", "https"); // Intentionally wrong; use www.google.com to make it work

    // Print the resolved endpoints
    for (const auto& endpoint : endpoints)
        std::cerr << endpoint << std::endl;

    co_return;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        net::io_context ctx;
        net::co_spawn(
            ctx,
            main2(),
            [&](std::exception_ptr eptr)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (eptr)
                        std::rethrow_exception(eptr);
                }
                catch (const std::exception& e)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
                }
            });
        ctx.run();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Uncaught exception\n";
    }
    return 0;
}


The solution to this ticket is I suspect the solution to both tickets.
Just to reiterate the problem:  The code above works fine when passed a reasonable address (e.g., "www.google.com") but fails to throw an exception out of async_resolve() when passed an unreasonable address (e.g., "www.googleqqq.com").
What happens instead is that this prints out:
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type boost::system::system_error: Host not found (authoritative) [asio.netdb:1]

and SIGABRT occurs (which probably means std::terminate was called).  So none of the exception catching stuff in the code above was hit.

What behavior do you expect and what do you see instead? I expect the message "uncaught exception"

Have you tried passing a completion handler instead of asio::detached?

@sehe My expectation is that "Resolve exception" prints out since the problem occurs in async_resolve() and there's a try/catch around that.

@sehe I edited the code (see changes above) to have a completion handler instead of asio::detached.  Same result as before.

Ah, so the problem is not at all that the exception isn’t raised. Instead, the problem is that it cannot be caught. What platform is this? I notice libc++abi so it might be OSX? More importantly: is dynamic linking involved?

Oh, and re: expectations (“and there’s a try-catch around that”) the std::cerr output streaming is lacking a flush, so it might not appear but might have executred. I suggest changing the ‘\n’ to std::endl or similar.

@sehe it is indeed macos.  I think what’s happenning is that inside of asio the exception is thrown but in the call stack there is a noexcept method.  Either that or their coroutine promose_type didn’t implement unhandled_exception() or rethrow properly.  As for std::cerr I think it flushes automatically (as opposed to std::clog.  And yes to dynamic linking I think.

Again regrowing doesn't seem to be missing because the exception is clearly raised (but not caught). I'd suspect that one of the usual ABI culprits is at play, regardless of coroutines. If RTTI is duplicated in different dynamically linked modules this can make exceptions effectively "foreign" during catch

@sehe I've tracked it down to this code in boost awaitable.hpp:   void rethrow_exception()
{
if (pending_exception_)
{
std::exception_ptr ex = std::exchange(pending_exception_, nullptr);
std::rethrow_exception(ex);
}
}  -- The exception never makes it out of this method (SIGABRT happens).  The method isn't noexcept...

The answer is "it's a bug" (credit to @sehe for mentioning dynamic linking).
Relevant info: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/92121
Solution (in CMakeLists.txt, assuming MacOS):
execute_process(
    COMMAND brew --prefix llvm
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE LLVM_PREFIX
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
        ${LLVM_PREFIX}/lib/libunwind.dylib
)


Great find. Thanks for sharing the solution. I would never have found this, for lack of a OSX machine.
